# How can i export the member list of a exchange online dynamic distribution group to inc the attribute employeenumber

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, dynamicquery, exchange-management-shell, office365-exchange

How can i export the members list of a exchange online dynamic distribution group to inc the attribute employeenumber?
EmployeeNumber is an onprem attribute but we have synced this to Azure AD using Directory Sync
i would like a export of all users in the exchange online dynamic distribution group "allcompanyusers"
i would like it to include
the username, email address and the employeenumber
i believe employeenumber is different in azure ad?

i have ran the following command however the employeenumber is empty
the display name and email address is populated

Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter (get-dynamicdistributiongroup Allcompanyusers).RecipientFilter -OrganizationalUnit $group.RecipientContainer | Select Displayname,alias,PrimarySmtpAddress,employeenumber | Export-Csv "c:\scripts\allcompanyusers.csv" -Notypeinformation